# Rails migrations task already started error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I have a Rails that is currently deployed on Kubernetes. The entrypoint of the app's image is this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

cd /usr/src/app

foreman run bundle exec rake db:migrate

exec "$@"
```

We have around 10 pods and all of them run the same startup command.
Now, everytime I redeploy, apply something, every time the pod is restarted, I see this on console:

```
E, [2018-03-06T11:10:26.212305 #9] ERROR -- : RAKE_TASK_INFO: task db:migrate started at 06-03-18 11:10:26 UTC
```

I think that I had a concurrency issue before when I fired up 10 pods and they all tried to run `rails db:migrate` and now I have the feeling that something is horribly wrong.

Is there something I can do? Something on the database to remove the lock? I tried to shutdown all pods and restart but I see the same message on console

Comment: Is there a difference between an entrypoint and a startup file ? I have a similar setup, rails on kub and many pods, starting my containers with  `CMD ./start.sh` in Dockerfile, start.sh being an executable containing the migration command and a `foreman start`. everything work ok